# piglatin translator java

Tags: java, translation, apache-pig

I am working on a pig latin translator which translator the given word into pig latin. Here is the pig latin method and the isVowel method.

```
public static void pigLatin(String s) {
        char[] array = s.trim().toCharArray();
        if(isVowel(s.charAt(0)) && !Character.toString(s.charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            System.out.println(s+"way");
        }else {
            int i = 0;
            String toReturn = "";
            do {
                toReturn += array[i];
                i++;
            }while(!isVowel(s.charAt(i)) && !Character.toString(array[i]).equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
            System.out.println(s.substring(i)+toReturn+"ay");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        char[] vowels = new char[] {'a','e','i','o','u','y'};
        for(int i = 0;i<vowels.length;i++) {
            if(Character.toString(vowels[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(Character.toString(c))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is when I input words "BIrD" and "quiet". First one throws `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4`
The second one doesn't convert properly. Quiet prints uietqay, when it supposes to be ietquay, but that doesn't make sense because, you supposed to take all constants upto the vowel, which should mean uietquay so why is it ietquay? Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

NOTE: This is not homework.

Comment: *Quiet prints uietqay, when it supposes to be ietquay, but that doesn't make sense because, you supposed to take all constants upto the vowel, which should mean uietquay so why is it ietquay?* **Huh?**  Are you asking *us* to teach you the rules of piglatin?  Get a firm grasp on what your requirements are before asking for help in making a program conform to them.  We're not here to give you your requirements.

Comment: I'm just explaining to you what is happening... I know what the requirements are. I have clearly displayed them in my comment `your supposed to take all constants upto the vowel`.

Comment: If you're "supposed to take all constants up to the vowel," why do you also say, "it supposes [sic] to be ietquay"?  Those two statements are mutually exclusive.  They can't both be true.  And there is nothing "clear" about that paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring case, Is that a "BLRD" or a "bird"? Because if it has no vowels, your do-while loop doesn't terminate except by going out of bounds.

Your second case, "quiet" should be "uietqay" unless you want to add special logic to keep "qu" together. You could accomplish this in your while condition by making it uglier:

```
while( (!isVowel(s.charAt(i)) || isQU(s, i)) && !Character.toString(array[i]).equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

And then implement the appropriate `isQU(String s, int index)`.

But I'd suggest that a little more rewriting is in order to make your code more readable. As is, I'm not quite sure why your `isVowel` checks for "y" and your while condition also checks for "y". Some of the time you use `array[i]` and some of the time you use `charAt(i)`. This inconsistency makes your code harder to read with little or no benefit.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. my `isVowel` checks for "y" because I am also using it somewhere else in the code and for that I need it to check if "y" is a vowel.

Comment: I wasn't disputing that you may have a reason for it. But it still makes your code harder to read. A simple fix: Add a comment. If you go back to this code in a month or ask an internet stranger to look at the code, you'll be glad you improved readability.

Comment: okay, I will take that into account, I was just explaining why I did that but commentating would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static String pigLatin(String a){
    a=a.toLowerCase();
    String [] x=a.split(" ");
    int vowl=0;
    String c="";
    String d="";
    String trans="";
    for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
       for(int j = 0;j<x[i].length();j++){
           if(x[i].charAt(j)=='a'||x[i].charAt(j)=='e'||x[i].charAt(j)=='i'||x[i].charAt(j)=='o'||x[i].charAt(j)=='u'){
               vowl=j;
               j=x[i].length();
            }
        }
       c=x[i].substring(0,vowl);
       d=x[i].substring(vowl,x[i].length());
       trans+= d+c+"ay ";
    }
    return trans;
}
```

Comment: Coming up with a new answer, 3 months after the first answer was accepted - don't you think it would be a good idea to explain in a few words, why your solution is a good or even better alternative?